# PHPSecLib RSA keys and VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

**Short desc:**

I need to generate RSA keypair in PHP and then be able to use it in VB.NET to encrypt/decrypt files/strings.

My file encrypt/decrypt VB.NET: http://jandrozd.eu/RSAFileEncryption.zip

Based on this: http://www.tma.dk/rsa/

Works with .NET generated keys, not with PHPSecLib generated keys.

**Details:**

I'm creating internal information system for one company. This IS is based on VB.NET desktop client and PHP server. Due to customer security requiriments, we're forced to use RSA encryption while storing files or strings. It also needs to be encrypted while/before transferring.

I was looking for code in PHP, which generates RSA key pair. I found phpseclib, which generates it well. I use this on server:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_XML);

//define('CRYPT_RSA_EXPONENT', 65537);
//define('CRYPT_RSA_SMALLEST_PRIME', 64); // makes it so multi-prime RSA is used
extract($rsa->createKey(512)); // == $rsa->createKey(1024) where 1024 is the key size
```

I also store text files with keys generated. The problem comes when i try to encrypt and decrypt with those keys in VB.NET. **Encrypting with phpseclib generated keys seems to work well in VB.NET, but I'm unable to decrypt files in VB.NET, strings with "Bad data error"** Base file decrypt vb code

```
Public Sub EncryptFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strNewPath As String, ByVal strPublicKey As String)
        Try
            If File.Exists(strFilePath) Then
                Dim bts() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(strFilePath)

                Dim EncryptedMessage As RSAResult = RSA.Encrypt(bts, strPublicKey)

                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(strNewPath, EncryptedMessage.AsBytes, False)
                If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("Encryption complete", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("File to encrypt does not exists", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("Encryption error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub DecryptFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strNewPath As String, ByVal strPrivateKey As String)
        Try
            If File.Exists(strFilePath) Then
                Dim bts() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(strFilePath)

                Dim DecryptedMessage As RSAResult = RSA.Decrypt(bts, strPrivateKey)

                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(strNewPath, DecryptedMessage.AsBytes, False)
                If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("Decryption complete", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("File to encrypt does not exists", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If EnableMessageBoxes Then MsgBox("Decryption error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

VB.NET RSA Class

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Public Class RSA
    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal Data As String, ByVal Publickey As String) As RSAResult
        Try
            Dim ByteConverter As New UnicodeEncoding()
            Return Encrypt(ByteConverter.GetBytes(Data), Publickey)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Encrypt(String): " & ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal Data() As Byte, ByVal Publickey As String) As RSAResult
        Try
            Dim RSA As System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider = New System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider()
            RSA.FromXmlString(Publickey)
            Return New RSAResult(RSAEncrypt(Data, RSA.ExportParameters(False), False))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Encrypt(Bytes): " & ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal Data() As Byte, ByVal Privatekey As String) As RSAResult
        Try
            Dim RSA As System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider = New System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider()
            RSA.FromXmlString(Privatekey)
            Dim Result As New RSAResult(RSADecrypt(Data, RSA.ExportParameters(True), False))
            Return Result
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Decrypt(): " & ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Shared Function RSAEncrypt(ByVal DataToEncrypt() As Byte, ByVal RSAKeyInfo As RSAParameters, ByVal DoOAEPPadding As Boolean) As Byte()
        Try
            Dim encryptedData() As Byte
            Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding)
            End Using
            Return encryptedData
        Catch e As CryptographicException
            Throw New Exception("RSAEncrypt(): " & e.Message, e)
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Shared Function RSADecrypt(ByVal DataToDecrypt() As Byte, ByVal RSAKeyInfo As RSAParameters, ByVal DoOAEPPadding As Boolean) As Byte()
        Try
            Dim decryptedData() As Byte
            Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding)
            End Using
            Return decryptedData
        Catch e As CryptographicException
            Throw New Exception("RSADecrypt(): " & e.Message, e)
        End Try
    End Function
```

RSAResult class:

```
Imports System.Text
Public Class RSAResult
    Private _Data() As Byte
    Public Sub New(ByVal Data() As Byte)
        _Data = Data
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property AsBytes() As Byte()
        Get
            Return _Data
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property AsString() As String
        Get
            Dim ByteConverter As New UnicodeEncoding()
            Return ByteConverter.GetString(_Data)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property AsBase64String() As String
        Get
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(_Data)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Example keys geenerated:

Private:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>AN3mGF2XtuTBC7jaBhPrVNYyheYX4HuCkhRpRXOCcKVOseahQBokzn555hIW0fK3kamVLOkSvSF6hP8rt1PC/Qs=</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <P>APeyh3iQRVNleEHNEx8cVCxYMIA7pCiSdYDGWJwf9meZ</P>
  <Q>AOVWMMpSkGlHtHe8aIgu9xw1lUiJ6VZIxVckPyj8oOBD</Q>
  <DP>AM20C+FKHuilSfuLbafWhOjWzGCSJ0AycTbigdAWkzFx</DP>
  <DQ>AMCTd7TtT8aYJ7rDwyNYDLjrZcfbxsxlnxBlp4PLX2vx</DQ>
  <InverseQ>AJ2/aZW5UR/pkQeA6BMKdhqqTWa5mjzMlnOga6zPlRdN</InverseQ>
  <D>AShwPBzMkYkIXKCWo4f4211MIZVCUKKvzHd4K1Ak8lfiTH4oxB8fgq4aa2QT5ufDwedlKGJLnuY6Kv9SpkMOIQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Public:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>AN3mGF2XtuTBC7jaBhPrVNYyheYX4HuCkhRpRXOCcKVOseahQBokzn555hIW0fK3kamVLOkSvSF6hP8rt1PC/Qs=</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: So you're using phpseclib to generate the keys but are then doing the encryption / decryption in VB.NET? Or are you doing just the encryption in VB.NET? phpseclib doesn't have a "Bad data error" error - just a "Decryption error" one. But maybe you're paraphrasing? idk

Comment: Yes,I wanna generate keys in phpseclib and then use them in VB.NET - here is simple .net example http://jandrozd.eu/RSAFileEncryption.zip - i wanna use keys from phpseclib in here. Im able to encrypt, but not able to decrypt.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this?
I am having the same issue but in the opposite direction.
I receive a public key from a .net server and I use it to encrypt data on linux (PHP) server.
When I encrypt in php and send it to the .net server, it fails the decrypt what I sent. 
See @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264842/rsa-encryption-from-from-c-sharp-to-php