# RSA encryption from From C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I need to connect to a certain webservice that uses RSA encryption. Using NuSOAP and PHPseclib I can connect to the server to get the public key used to RSA encrypt and send back data to the server.

Problem arise in the way they are encrypting the data, the developer there gave me documentation and sample written in C# to which is hard to comprehend and convert to PHP.
The only thing that needs to be encrypted is the password.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Dns.Lib.Compression;
    using Dns.Lib.Security.Cryptography;
    using ThirdPartyTest.ThirdPartyService;
    using SoapExtensionLib;

    private static string BaseServiceCall(int sysUserId, string password)
    {

            SecureMessageManager secureMessageManager = new SecureMessageManager();
            ThirdPartyService.Main client = new ThirdPartyService.Main();

            string dnPublicKey = client.GetPublicKey();//this is used to get the pbKey

            secureMessageManager.ImportThirdPartyRSAKey(dnPublicKey);

            string sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            string tokenRequestXml = @"<request>
<id>" + sysUserId + @"</id>
<password>" + secureMessageManager.RSAEncryptString(password) + @"</password>
<session>" + sessionId + @"</session>
<public>" + secureMessageManager.ExportPublicKey() + @"</public>
</request>";

            string tokenResonse = client.GetSommething(tokenRequestXml);
            //...
    }
```

Also what does `secureMessageManager.ExportPublicKey()` do?

Here is my PHP version of the above.

```
require_once('RSA-PHPseclib0.3.5/Crypt/RSA.php');
require_once('nusoap.php');
    $sysUserId  = '.....';
    $pass       = '.....';
    $sessionId  = session_id();
    $pubKey     = "<rsakeyvalue><modulus>kdT4UUBowCepvTU3panVLnAWqKSIik8eSc5Sog0e7BOP2EoNVwer5RfxIICaWzVpJtPAQJYQ9AaW4qpp3qIw3g3DR7OTw/lvif6y5VemiRue6u4T2eef4AG3Ka0MoMhTtMxIRXGNqx6hPyPn40F9ZMFwprFupFl0Z2LPRLR3Fek=</modulus><exponent>AQAB</exponent></rsakeyvalue>";//The Public key received from an other program

    $rsa        = new Crypt_RSA();
    $return     = $rsa->loadKey($pubKey);
    $password   = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($pass));

    $inputData  = "<request><id>$sysUserId</id><password>$password</password><session>$sessionId</session><public>$pubKey</public></request>";
    $params     = array('inputData'=>$inputData);
    $result     = $client->call('GetSommething', $params, $namespaces, '', '',null,'document','literal');
```

The error that I receive from they server is `'Server was unable to process request. ---> Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.'`. I have gather it has something to do with the way I encrypt the password. Having spent over 40 hours hitting a brick wall, not sure what to do.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what SecureMessageManager does? Where did that class come from?

Comment: I did not write the C# code, it was an example given to me to follow (but I am more PHP developer).
The `SecureMessageManager` class is probably a class created from one of the included library. I am hopping someone know about this and could clarify

Comment: I guess the first thing I'm curious about is...  what do the contents of $_SESSION['token'] look like? Is it a format phpseclib supports? You can test this by doing `echo $rsa;`

Comment: the format for $_SESSION['token'] is `<rsakeyvalue><modulus>kdT4UUBowCepvTU3panVLnAWqKSIik8eSc5Sog0e7BOP2EoNVwer5RfxIICaWzVpJtPAQJYQ9AaW4qpp3qIw3g3DR7OTw/lvif6y5VemiRue6u4T2eef4AG3Ka0MoMhTtMxIRXGNqx6hPyPn40F9ZMFwprFupFl0Z2LPRLR3Fek=</modulus><exponent>AQAB</exponent></rsakeyvalue>` I saved it in a session because it was genereated from an other page

Comment: I am voting to close. By leaving out the most important details this becomes an impossible to answer question. Also, if by some miracle another developer who is familiar with SecureMessageManager appears to answer *your* question it will do little to help puzzled folks who come by here for help in the future.

Comment: $_SESSION['token'] looks good. Can you get SecureMessageManager to encrypt some text and post the encrypted text produced by it? Maybe we can figure out the format it's expecting from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution [here](http://www.codeblog.co.uk/2011/08/02/web-development/using-php-to-encrypt-decrypt-sign-verify-data-with-a-net-generated-xml-rsa-key/) and [Here](http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=18085&sid=308531406f939e6ebbc9997ccb990e5f)
There are some changes that needs to be made to the default phpseclib library to make it compatible to encrypt/decrypt with the .net libraries.
I am just surprised that Something as obvious as incompatibility between the way PHP encrypt/decrypt RSA and the way C# does it are somehow different but very few topic on it.

Comment: True, I also find it a bit surprising that not much information about this can be found, and I also needed some time to get a correct example working. But I did, starting with your provided links, and for future visitors, here is a complete working example of creating / exhanging public / private keys with C# and PHP and sending encrypted messages: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php.html

Comment: But now i have to correct myself, I figured that phpseclib already implements XML key formats - so now it has gotten pretty simple: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php_27.html (I recommend this solution over my previous comment).

Answer (score -1):

You should check msdn forum they have similar topic.
[encrypt with php](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90008dd9-ed2b-49c6-864e-b2540d98ef4f/how-can-i-use-the-key-file-generated-by-rsacryptoserviceprovider-to-encrypt-with-php)

On asp.net forum
[OAEP padding](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285821.aspx)

Comment: I have tested they library but unfortunately I still get the `OAEP Padding` error. The developer did ask me to convert the text to Byte before encrypting the data so I am trying that

Comment: Byte in PHP? I dont think that is a necessary step to encrypt with RSA.